# I want to navigate to another page using TouchableOpacity but failed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, touchableopacity

I want to navigate to another page using TouchableOpacity but failed
Navigating to other pages with Tab.Navigator works correctly. I created after that TouchableOpacity. Which is located in the middle of the other buttons and it should navigate to the scanner page
Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import MainScreen from "./view/MainPage";
import ProfileScreen from "./view/ProfilePage";
import ScanScreen from "./view/ScanPage";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const App = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator
          style={styles.tabBar}
          screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
              let iconName;

              if (route.name === "main") {
                iconName = focused ? "home" : "home";
              } else if (route.name === "scan") {
                iconName = focused ? "qrcode-scan" : "qrcode-scan";
              } else if (route.name === "profile") {
                iconName = focused ? "account" : "account";
              }

              return (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name={iconName}
                  size={size}
                  color={color}
                />
              );
            },
            tabBarLabel: "",
            tabBarActiveTintColor: "#1573FE",
            tabBarInactiveTintColor: "gray",
          })}
        >
          <Tab.Screen
            name="main"
            component={MainScreen}
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
         
          <Tab.Screen
            name="profile"
            component={ProfileScreen}
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
        </Tab.Navigator>

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.scanButton}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ScanScreen")}
        >
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="qrcode-scan" color="white" size={30} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </>
  );
};
```

This is what the page  where the TouchableOpacity navigate:

```
const ScanScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Text>This is the Scan screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

i just wanted to create a button
[image]

do you know another way to create a round button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a custom Button/Icon component to tabBarButton prop in options. That's how I handle it.

```
export const CustomTabBarButton = ({
  children,
  onPress,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  onPress: (e) => void;
}) => (
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={{
      top: -1,
      right: 9,
    }}
    onPress={onPress}
  >
    <View
      style={{
        width: 80,
        height: 80,
        borderRadius: 35,
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);




  <Tab.Screen
    name={SCREEN_CONFIG.SEARCH}
    component={Search}
    options={{
      headerShown: false,
      title: SCREEN_CONFIG.SEARCH,
      tabBarLabelPosition: "below-icon",
      tabBarButton: props => (
        <CustomTabBarButton
          onPress={e => {
            props.onPress?.(e);
          }}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: COLORS[theme].TAB_BAR_BG,
              borderRadius: 50,
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center"
            }}
          >
            <PlusIcon />
          </View>
        </CustomTabBarButton>
      )
    }}
  />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('/details')}>
```

{/* Your button content */}

Comment: I tried that too, it doesn't work. an error comes out: navigaite is not defuned

Comment: check  the page direct without any click open url like (http://example.com/ScanScreen

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: get your page direct just like i mention above   if it is working then there will be an issue in the code for navigate  if page is not accessible then  set the page path

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Create the custom component. Because `navigation` prop doesn't exist. You can get `navigation` only under `NavigationContainer` component.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export const Button = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigation();

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.scanButton}
      onPress={() => navigate('ScanScreen')}>
      <MaterialCommunityIcons name="qrcode-scan" color="white" size={30} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately this method doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`navigation` prop is passed to the `screen` components. you define the screen components inside the navigators. For example in your code, this is

```
    <Tab.Screen
        name="main"
        component={MainScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
```

a screen component and `MainScreen` will receive `navigation` and you can navigate to another screen component. your app component does not receive `navigation` prop

```
 // this is just a custom component, not a screen component
 const App = ({ navigation }) => {}
```

Also, if you did not register the `ScanScreen` as a screen component inside a  navigator, it will not receive `navigation` prop

```
// you have to register this as a screen component
const ScanScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Text>This is the Scan screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the name of the component is correctly spelled i.e ScanScreen is the same as in your routes file .Secondly check whether they both are in same stack .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

App component is not directly associated with the navigation stack, it doesn't have direct access to the navigation prop. To resolve this, you can wrap the App component with the NavigationContainer and move the TouchableOpacity inside the MainScreen component.

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        style={styles.tabBar}
        screenOptions={screenOptions}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          name="main"
          component={MainScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="scan"
          component={ScanScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="profile"
          component={ProfileScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

MainScreen component, you can add the TouchableOpacity for scanning:

```js
const MainScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Main Screen</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.scanButton}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("scan")}
      >
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="qrcode-scan" color="white" size={30} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: Add a couple of lines in MainScreen,'import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";' and '  const navigation = useNavigation();' inside the function. and now try this . If this is also not working I would like to see more of your codes